# Have anyone managed to use windows+anaconda+tensorflow combination?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

If anyone did it successfully, please share the procedure with simple steps.
I am using win 8, anaconda 3.

Probably one guy from Spyder team will join and write, the problem is not related to spyder, as usual, lol

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Anaconda for windows from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/)
2. Create the new environment called 'py35'. Open Windows command prompt and type:

   `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda`

   This automatically installs python 3.5 in the new environment.
3. Now, activate the environment by typing the following into the command prompt:

   `activate py35`
4. The command prompt should now change to have a (py35)  at the beginning of each line. This indicates that we're working in the new py35 environment.
5. Install the Packages:

   `conda install spyder
   conda install tensorflow (cpu-version)`

   Hopefully this should complete without errors. If you're having trouble getting tensorflow to work try:
   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`
6. If you want to install the GPU version of tensorflow, just type:
   `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

   Now, suppose you want to open spyder, open windows command prompt and type `activate py35`. Type `spyder` and press enter.

   Check if tensorflow is properly installed or not using `import tensorflow`.